# MYSQL Duplicating Array Value

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<pre>";

// DISTRIBUTE TEAMS INTO CONTESTS
$fixtures = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT teamname FROM tourn_teams WHERE groupname='Group 1'");

$teams = array();
// THE TEAMS
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fixtures))
{ 

  $teams[] = $row['teamname'];

}

// HOW MANY WEEKS
$weeks = 3;

// MAKE ENOUGH ARRAY ELEMENTS FOR THE DISTRIBUTION
$array = array_merge($teams, $teams);


// POPULATE THE MATCHES ARRAY
$matches = array();
while ($weeks)
{
    foreach ($teams as $ptr => $team)
    {
        // FIND THE INDEX INTO THE DISTRIBUTION ARRAY
        $linkt = $ptr + $weeks;

        // SELECT THE HOME AND AWAY TEAMS
        $home = $team;
        $away = $array[$linkt];
        $matches[$team][$weeks] = array('home' => $home, 'away' => $away);
    }

    // NEXT WEEK
    $weeks--;
}


// SORT THE MATCHES SENSIBLY SO WEEK ONE COMES FIRST
foreach ($matches as $team => $contests)
{
    ksort($contests);
    $matches[$team] = $contests;
}


// ACTIVATE THIS TO SEE WHAT THE $matches ARRAY LOOKS LIKE
// print_r($matches);


// CREATE THE TABLE OF MATCHUPS
$out = NULL;
$out .= "<table>";
$out .= PHP_EOL;


// CREATE THE HEADERS FOR EACH WEEK
$weeknums = end($matches);

$out .= "<tr>";
$out .= '<th> Team </th>';
$out .= '<th> v </th>';
$out .= "<th> Team </th>";
$out .= '</tr>';
$out .= PHP_EOL;


// CREATE THE MATRIX OF MATCHUPS
foreach ($matches as $team => $contests)
{
    $out .= "<form class='form-horizontal' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'d method='post'><tr><td><input type='text' name='teamone' value='$team' readonly></td>";
    $out .= "<td> <b>v</b></td>";
    foreach ($contests as $week => $matchup)
    {
print_r($matchup);
        $out .= "<td> <input type='text' name='teamtwo' value='{$matchup["away"]}' readonly> </td>";
    }
    $out .= "</tr>";
    $out .= PHP_EOL;
}
$out .= "<input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='submit'></form></table>";
$out .= PHP_EOL;

foreach ($matches as $team => $contests)
{
foreach ($contests as $week => $matchup)
    {
    if(is_array($matchup)){
    foreach($matchup as $key => $value){
    $home = $matchup['home'];
    $away = $matchup[away];

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tourn_fixtures(teamone, teamtwo) values ('$home', '$away')");
    }
}
}
}


echo "</pre>";
echo $out;
```

So this is my code. When I try and run the sql query after // CREATE THE MATRIX OF MATCHUPS it works and does what I want except but it's inserting 2 of the same rows into the database.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9mSG.png)

I've been playing around and can't find out whats duplicating it. I just want one row and not 2 of the same rows.

Also I've just noticed, it generates two of the same fixtures later on...

[Duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPF75.png)

This is the output I get for the array;

```
    Array
(
    [home] => Committee All-Stars
    [away] => Vets
)
Array
(
    [home] => Committee All-Stars
    [away] => Lightning
)
Array
(
    [home] => Committee All-Stars
    [away] => Bolt
)
Array
(
    [home] => Vets
    [away] => Lightning
)
Array
(
    [home] => Vets
    [away] => Bolt
)
Array
(
    [home] => Vets
    [away] => Firsts
)
Array
(
    [home] => Lightning
    [away] => Bolt
)
Array
(
    [home] => Lightning
    [away] => Firsts
)
Array
(
    [home] => Lightning
    [away] => Committee All-Stars
)
Array
(
    [home] => Bolt
    [away] => Firsts
)
Array
(
    [home] => Bolt
    [away] => Committee All-Stars
)
Array
(
    [home] => Bolt
    [away] => Vets
)
Array
(
    [home] => Firsts
    [away] => Committee All-Stars
)
Array
(
    [home] => Firsts
    [away] => Vets
)
Array
(
    [home] => Firsts
    [away] => Lightning
)
```

I only want each team to play each other once.

Comment: I think the last `foreach()` might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your last `foreach`. `$matchup` is an array something like

```
Array
(
    [home] => All-Stars
    [away] => Vets
)
```

and you are iterating over its values, so you are doing two inserts for each matchup. You don't actually need the `foreach` there, just use

```
foreach ($contests as $week => $matchup) {
    $home = $matchup['home'];
    $away = $matchup['away'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tourn_fixtures(teamone, teamtwo) values ('$home', '$away')");
}
```

Note that you also need quotes around `away` as an index to `$matchup`.

Here's a demo of your code showing the generation of two `INSERT` queries for each `$matchup`: [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gFepV)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the response, on a better track! - When the INSERT statement runs it creates the tables but I only want each team to play each other once. `Array
(
    [home] => All-Stars
    [away] => Lightning
)` and it also creats `Array
(
    [home] => Lightning
    [away] => All-Stars
)` how can I stop this from happening ?

Comment: @LouieHeaton that's a trickier problem because you need to make sure each team plays at home and away the same number of times. It's probably worthy of another question...

Comment: @LouieHeaton If you ask another question I would suggest simplifying it to show just the `$matches` array (the output from the commented `print_r($matches)` in your code) and say that you want to alter that so that each team plays each other only once, with an equal number of games home and away.

Comment: @LouieHeaton I can't see your new question under your user account. If you don't have a solution yet, can you comment with a link?